# Parsing Indentation-based syntaxes in Haskell's Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, indentation, parsec

I'm trying to parse an indentation-based language (think Python, Haskell itself, Boo, YAML) in Haskell using Parsec. I've seen the IndentParser library, and it looks like it's the perfect match, but what I can't figure out is how to make my `TokenParser` into an indentation parser. Here's the code I have so far:

```
import qualified Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Token as T
import qualified Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.IndentParser.Token as IT

lexer = T.makeTokenParser mylangDef
ident = IT.identifier    lexer
```

This throws the error:

```
parser2.hs:29:28:
    Couldn't match expected type `IT.TokenParser st'
             against inferred type `T.GenTokenParser s u m'
    In the first argument of `IT.identifier', namely `lexer'
    In the expression: IT.identifier lexer
    In the definition of `ident': ident = IT.identifier lexer
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I create an `IT.TokenParser`? Or is IndentParser broken and to be avoided?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you're using Parsec 3 here, while IndentParser expects Parsec 2. Your example compiles for me with `-package parsec-2.1.0.1`.

So IndentParser isn't necessarily broken, but the author(s) should have been more specific about versions in the list of dependencies. It's possible to have both versions of Parsec installed, so there's no reason you shouldn't use IndentParser unless you're committed to using Parsec 3 for other reasons.

---

**UPDATE:** Actually no changes to the source are necessary to get IdentParser working with Parsec 3. The problem that both of us were having seems to be caused by the fact that `cabal-install` has a ["soft preference"](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg47149.html) for Parsec 2. You can simply reinstall IndentParser with an explicit constraint on the Parsec version:

```
cabal install IndentParser --reinstall --constraint="parsec >= 3"
```

Alternatively you can download the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/IndentParser/0.2.1/IndentParser-0.2.1.tar.gz) and [build and install in the normal way](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/Cabal/builders.html).

Comment: You, sir, are awesome! Thank you! How did you know I was using Parsec 3? A guess? Because I think my example could be either...

Comment: I'm afraid that my detective work here wasn't actually very exciting: I compiled your code with Parsec 3, got an error similar to yours, and then tried Parsec 2, which worked. By the way, it looks like it wouldn't be too hard to get IndentParser working with Parsec 3; you might consider giving it a shot if you find IndentParser useful.

Comment: I might, but right now I'm only just learning Haskell; I'm afraid I would get lost in a foreign codebase like that.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a set of parser combinators I put together for Parsec 3 that can be used for Haskell style layout, that might be of use to you. The key considerations are that `laidout` starts and runs a layout rule, and that you should use the `space` and `spaced` combinators provided rather than the stock `Parsec` combinators for the same purpose. Due to the interaction of layout and comments I had to merge the comment parsing into the tokenizer.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
module Text.Parsec.Layout
    ( laidout          -- repeat a parser in layout, separated by (virtual) semicolons
    , space            -- consumes one or more spaces, comments, and onside newlines in a layout rule
    , maybeFollowedBy
    , spaced           -- (`maybeFollowedBy` space)
    , LayoutEnv        -- type needed to describe parsers
    , defaultLayoutEnv -- a fresh layout
    , semi             -- semicolon or virtual semicolon
    ) where

import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Control.Monad (guard)

import Data.Char (isSpace)

import Text.Parsec.Combinator
import Text.Parsec.Pos
import Text.Parsec.Prim hiding (State)
import Text.Parsec.Char hiding (space)

data LayoutContext = NoLayout | Layout Int deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

data LayoutEnv = Env
    { envLayout :: [LayoutContext]
    , envBol :: Bool -- if true, must run offside calculation
    }

defaultLayoutEnv :: LayoutEnv
defaultLayoutEnv = Env [] True

pushContext :: Stream s m c => LayoutContext -> ParsecT s LayoutEnv m ()
pushContext ctx = modifyState $ \env -> env { envLayout = ctx:envLayout env }

popContext :: Stream s m c => String -> ParsecT s LayoutEnv m ()
popContext loc = do
    (_:xs) <- envLayout <$> getState
    modifyState $ \env' -> env' { envLayout = xs }
  <|> unexpected ("empty context for " ++ loc)

getIndentation :: Stream s m c => ParsecT s LayoutEnv m Int
getIndentation = depth . envLayout <$> getState where
    depth :: [LayoutContext] -> Int
    depth (Layout n:_) = n
    depth _ = 0

pushCurrentContext :: Stream s m c => ParsecT s LayoutEnv m ()
pushCurrentContext = do
    indent <- getIndentation
    col <- sourceColumn <$> getPosition
    pushContext . Layout $ max (indent+1) col

maybeFollowedBy :: Stream s m c => ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m b -> ParsecT s u m a
t `maybeFollowedBy` x = do t' <- t; optional x; return t'

spaced :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s LayoutEnv m a -> ParsecT s LayoutEnv m a
spaced t = t `maybeFollowedBy` space

data Layout = VSemi | VBrace | Other Char deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

-- TODO: Parse C-style #line pragmas out here
layout :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s LayoutEnv m Layout
layout = try $ do
    bol <- envBol <$> getState
    whitespace False (cont bol)
  where
    cont :: Stream s m Char => Bool -> Bool -> ParsecT s LayoutEnv m Layout
    cont True = offside
    cont False = onside

    -- TODO: Parse nestable {-# LINE ... #-} pragmas in here
    whitespace :: Stream s m Char =>
        Bool -> (Bool -> ParsecT s LayoutEnv m Layout) -> ParsecT s LayoutEnv m Layout
    whitespace x k =
            try (string "{-" >> nested k >>= whitespace True)
        <|> try comment
        <|> do newline; whitespace True offside
        <|> do tab; whitespace True k
        <|> do (satisfy isSpace <?> "space"); whitespace True k
        <|> k x

    comment :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s LayoutEnv m Layout
    comment = do
        string "--"
        many (satisfy ('\n'/=))
        newline
        whitespace True offside

    nested :: Stream s m Char =>
        (Bool -> ParsecT s LayoutEnv m Layout) ->
        ParsecT s LayoutEnv m (Bool -> ParsecT s LayoutEnv m Layout)
    nested k =
            try (do string "-}"; return k)
        <|> try (do string "{-"; k' <- nested k; nested k')
        <|> do newline; nested offside
        <|> do anyChar; nested k

    offside :: Stream s m Char => Bool -> ParsecT s LayoutEnv m Layout
    offside x = do
        p <- getPosition
        pos <- compare (sourceColumn p) <$> getIndentation
        case pos of
            LT -> do
                popContext "the offside rule"
                modifyState $ \env -> env { envBol = True }
                return VBrace
            EQ -> return VSemi
            GT -> onside x

    -- we remained onside.
    -- If we skipped any comments, or moved to a new line and stayed onside, we return a single a ' ',
    -- otherwise we provide the next char
    onside :: Stream s m Char => Bool -> ParsecT s LayoutEnv m Layout
    onside True = return $ Other ' '
    onside False = do
        modifyState $ \env -> env { envBol = False }
        Other <$> anyChar

layoutSatisfies :: Stream s m Char => (Layout -> Bool) -> ParsecT s LayoutEnv m ()
layoutSatisfies p = guard . p =<< layout

virtual_lbrace :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s LayoutEnv m ()
virtual_lbrace = pushCurrentContext

virtual_rbrace :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s LayoutEnv m ()
virtual_rbrace = try (layoutSatisfies (VBrace ==) <?> "outdent")

-- recognize a run of one or more spaces including onside carriage returns in layout
space :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s LayoutEnv m String
space = do
    try $ layoutSatisfies (Other ' ' ==)
    return " "
  <?> "space"

-- recognize a semicolon including a virtual semicolon in layout
semi :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s LayoutEnv m String
semi = do
    try $ layoutSatisfies p
    return ";"
  <?> "semi-colon"
  where
        p VSemi = True
        p (Other ';') = True
        p _ = False

lbrace :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s LayoutEnv m String
lbrace = do
    char '{'
    pushContext NoLayout
    return "{"

rbrace :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s LayoutEnv m String
rbrace = do
    char '}'
    popContext "a right brace"
    return "}"

laidout :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s LayoutEnv m a -> ParsecT s LayoutEnv m [a]
laidout p = try (braced statements) <|> vbraced statements where
    braced = between (spaced lbrace) (spaced rbrace)
    vbraced = between (spaced virtual_lbrace) (spaced virtual_rbrace)
    statements = p `sepBy` spaced semi
```

Comment: Can you give an example of using this? I tried it [like this](https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/af1829b18ea80e21ba79728a5d271cd9) but I can't get `bindings` to accept something even as simple as `unlines ["x = y", "a = b"]`.

Comment: I currently think the above source is broken, but I haven't had a chance to revisit it.